# Setar objeto em Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de listagem:

```
<div style="position: fixed;z-index: 999;top:20%;margin:0 auto;left:25%;width:50%;padding:5%;background:#FFF;"  ng-if="templateForm == 'light-box-selectcasa'"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>SELECIONE UMA CASA PARA LISTAR AS INFORMAÇÕES</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="item as item.referencia for item in casas.list track by item.id" ng-model="obj.casa"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="setCasa()">SELECIONAR CASA</button>
    </div>
    <div style="position:fixed;width:1px;height:1px;float:left;"><img style="position:relative;float:left;right:190px;bottom:50px;" src="<?= base_url('assets/img/man-calendar.png') ?>"/></div>
</div>
```

A listagem, está correta, lista os itens do banco de dados e etc.

E tenho então a função dentro do angular, setCasa():

```
var casaRef = '';
app.controller("agendaController", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.setCasa = function () {
        casaRef = $scope.obj.casa;
        $scope.template = '';
        $scope.templateForm = '';
    };
}
```

Porém quando para a ação do setCasa, se eu der um alert em casaRef, ele vem somente com [object Object].

Como repassar esta variável para que quando eu der o alert, chegue então o que foi selecionado?

Comment: Coloca alert(JSON.stringify(casaRef));

Comment: Apareceu um monte de coisas agora rsrs

Comment: É isso ou você quer algo diferente?

Comment: Assim deu certo oh alert(JSON.stringify(casaRef['id'])); só que mesmo assim, não sei como setar a variavel casaRef, com este id

Comment: Então acho que seu ng-model está setando o obj.casa com o array inteiro de opções e não com a selecionada. Provavelmente o ng-options tá com algum problema. Vou analisa-lo

Comment: Este aqui casaRef = $scope.obj.casa; tem que estar setado o que veio do list..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47916/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-sorack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o ng-option da seguinte forma para obter apenas o `id` da casa selecionada:

```
ng-options="item.id as item.referencia for item in casas.list"
```

Ou utilize da seguinte forma para obter o objeto completo, com referência:

```
ng-options="item as item.referencia for item in casas.list"
```